# Split string by space than change text color of each word

Tags: jquery, css, string

I have a string that needs to be splitted in order to change the color of each word.

This is my HTML Code

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="title"><Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span>
    <span class="title"><Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus libero lectus. </span>
    <span class="title"><Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur est mi egestas nec lacus eget finibus  </span>
</div>
```

Up to five words the colors need to be:

- 1st word: #EE7F00
- 2nd word: #EA650D
- 3rd word: #E64415
- 4th word: #EA650D
- 5th word: #EE7F00

Six to twelve words it needs to be the same only every two words changes colors

And more than twelve words needs too change every three words.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start:

```
// iterate throught the .title spans
$('.title').each(function(idx) {

    // get the text from the span
    var txt = $(this).text();

    // split the words separated by a space into an array
    var words = txt.split(" ");
    var html = "";

    // iterate through the words and wrap them with a span and color 
    for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        html += '<span style="color:'+getColor(i)+';">'+words[i]+'</span> ' ;
    }

    // write the generated html back to the dom
    $(this).html(html);
});

function getColor(i) {
    var color = "";
    if(i == 0) color = "#EE7F00";
    else if(i == 1) color = "#EA650D";
    else if(i == 2) color = "#E64415";
    else if(i == 3) color = "#EA650D";
    else if(i == 4) color = "#EE7F00";   
    else if(i >= 5 && i <= 11) return getColor(Math.floor((i - 5) / 2));
    else if(i >= 12) return getColor(Math.floor((i - 12) / 3));
    return color;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if I got the color logic right, so the getColor function is for determining the color based on the index of the current word.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nos5mt7x/

Comment: Thank you i had no idea where to start but this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the keywords here for you should be

- Modulus, returns division remainder: e.g.

  5%2 = 1
- Split function javascript:

  array.split(" ");
- each function jquery (apply a function to each element of an array, see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/)
- the join function from javascript to combine an array.

So the code could look like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbpaw8aw/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Color list
    //var arrColors = ["#EE7F00", "#EA650D", "#E64415", "#EA650D", "#EE7F00"];
    // some colors that are more distinct
    var arrColors = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#ff00ff", "#000000"];

    // the span you'd like to check
    var spantext = ".from-twelve";

    var textstr = $(spantext).text().trim();
    // remove the text from the DOM
    $(spantext).empty();
    var arrTextstr = textstr.split(" ");
    var ci = 0;
    $.each(arrTextstr, function(index, value) {
        // get the index of the color list
        if(arrTextstr.length<= 5) {
            ci = (index+1)%5;
        } else if(arrTextstr.length<=12) {
            ci = ((index+1+(index+1)%2)/2-1)%5;    
        } else {
            ci = ((index-index%3)/3)%5;
        }
        // colorize the word
        arrTextstr[index] = "<font color=\""+arrColors[ci]+"\">"+value+"</font>";
    });
    // reattach the text
    $(spantext).append(arrTextstr.join(" "));
});
```

The only thing now is, that each word is "colored" seperatly. I don't know if that is a problem for you, but at least it works :-)

Cheers
R

Comment: First what if he want to add this to more than 1 class in that case your code merge all the text with same class in one big span. better to use .each for the main class

Second why you not directly loop through the color array and add to each text array index in this case you dont need to count the letter